# Concate string to variable in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I need to check for dot at the trailing end of domain name and add the dot at the end of domain name if it's not exist. Both code below I test it but both query won't execute.

```
if(substr($_SESSION['domain'], -1) != '.') {
    $append = $_SESSION['domain'].= '.';
    $tank5 = "UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET act='N' WHERE ori='{$append}'";
    $result5 = mysql_query($tank5);
    if (!$result5) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

if(substr($_SESSION['domain'], -1) != '.') {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET act='N' WHERE ori={$_SESSION['domain']. '.'}")
}
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm, `UPDATE dns SET ori = CONCAT(ori,'.') WHERE ori NOT LIKE '%.'`? Or am I missing soething?

Answer (score 0):

The problem had been solved. The description I gave is not clear and please forgive me for wasting anyone time. Part of the problem is session variable between tab pages.

```
if ($_SESSION['domain'] != ''){

if(substr($_SESSION['domain'], -1) != '.') {

    $append = $_SESSION['domain'].= '.';
    mysql_query("UPDATE `db`.`dns` SET active='N' WHERE ori='{$append}'");
    }

}


}
```

I now check if the session even exist. That is part of the problem that I not put in the question above. My apologies again for wasting anyone time.